# Использование параметров командной строки в Inno

Tags: inno-setup

Можно ли создать инсталятор который принимал бы параметры командной строки? Если да то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Парсинг параметра из командной строки и запись его в файл

```
[INI]
Filename: "{app}\settings.conf"; Section: "MainSettings"; Key: "ip";       String: "{code:ParsingIP|ip}"
Filename: "{app}\settings.conf"; Section: "MainSettings"; Key: "port";     String: "{code:ParsingPort|port}"
Filename: "{app}\settings.conf"; Section: "MainSettings"; Key: "proxy_ip"; String: "{code:ParsingProxyIP|proxy_ip}"
Filename: "{app}\settings.conf"; Section: "MainSettings"; Key: "proxy_port"; String: "{code:ParsingProxyPort|proxy_port}"

[Code]
function ParsingIP(const Key: String): String;
var
i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ParamCount do begin
    Result := ParamStr(i-3);    
  end;  
end;


function ParsingPort(const Key: String): String;
var
i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ParamCount do begin
    Result := ParamStr(i-2);    
  end;  
end;

function ParsingProxyIP(const Key: String): String;
var
i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ParamCount do begin
    Result := ParamStr(i-1);    
  end;  
end;

function ParsingProxyPort(const Key: String): String;
var
i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ParamCount do begin
    Result := ParamStr(i);    
  end;  
end;
```

Comment: Для чего цикл по `i` в процедурах? `if ParamCount > 2 then Result := ParamStr(3) else Result := '';` не?

Comment: Это весьма топорный способ парсинга параметров

Comment: "Весьма топорный" это в моем комментарии, а то что написано в вашем ответе - это тихий ужас :)